# Результат не хочет каститься. NamedNativeQuery - SqlResultSetMapping

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Собственно он не хочет работать:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "viewSearchObjects",
    query = "select id, nomob, naimzak, naimob, datvk from v_search_objects",
    resultSetMapping = "v_search_objectsResult"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "v_search_objectsResult",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = ViewSearchObjects.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name="id", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="nomob", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="naimzak", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="naimob", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="datvk", type = Timestamp.class)
        }
    )
)
```

Если убрать @ConstructorResult, то получаю в виде списка Object, но это не устраивает.
Сам класс:

```
public class ViewSearchObjects {
    private final Long id;
    private final String numObject;
    private final String nameClient;
    private final String nameObject;
    private final Timestamp dateRelease;

    public ViewSearchObjects(Long id, String numObject, String nameClient,
            String nameObject, Timestamp dateRelease) {
        this.id = id;
        this.numObject = numObject;
        this.nameClient = nameClient;
        this.nameObject = nameObject;
        this.dateRelease = dateRelease;
    }
...
```

Вызываю так:

```
List<ViewSearchObjects> result = session.getNamedQuery("viewSearchObjects").getResultList();
```

Пишет:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : hibernate.entities.main.view.ViewSearchObjects
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.resolveConstructor(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:45)
...
```

Ну как нет конструктора, если он есть?
Делаю по https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "viewSearchObjects",
    query = "select " +
               "id, nomob as numObject, naimzak as nameClient, " +
               "naimob as nameObject, datvk as dateRelease " +
            "from v_search_objects",
    resultSetMapping = "v_search_objectsResult"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "v_search_objectsResult",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = ViewSearchObjects.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name="id", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="numObject", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="nameClient", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="nameObject", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="dateRelease", type = Timestamp.class)
        }
    )
)
```

Изменены запрос и имена колонок в `@ConstructorResult`.